# Rails, gmaps4rails don't work with https

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I am currently using Rails 3.0.9 and gmaps4rails 0.8.6.

I have a problem with enabling https for google maps.

I tried to use that sollution:

[Using gmaps4rails with https/SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681310/using-gmaps4rails-with-https-ssl)

But with no success.

In layout application I added this js include tags:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=geometry" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "https://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/infobox/1.1.5/src/infobox.js" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "gmaps4rails.js" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "https://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclusterer/1.0/src/markerclusterer_compiled.js" %>
```

My controller code

```
...
@places = Place.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
@json = @places.to_gmaps4rails
```

View

```
...
 <div id="mapLocal"> <%= gmaps4rails(@json, true false) %> </div>
...
```

After that google maps still work with http.

Page source code

```
function gmaps4rails_loadScript() {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.src = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=geometry&callback=gmaps4rails_init";
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

I tried to change gmaps4rails to gmaps.

Result:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 54ms


ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `to_gmaps4rails' for #<String:0xf5d98528>):
    13: <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    14: function gmaps4rails_init() {
    15:     <% #true is passed here to trigger map initialization %>
    16:     <%=raw options.to_gmaps4rails(true) %>
    17: }
    18:   
    19: function gmaps4rails_loadScript() {
  app/views/places/index.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_places_index_html_erb___671263203__86055108_0'
```

So I decided to upgrade gem(maybe the older version doesn't support ssl?).

After upgrade from 0.8.6 to 1.1.4 map isn't even generated with my basic, unchanged code

```
  <div id="mapLocal"> <%= gmaps4rails(@json) %> </div>
```

I checked js logs with firebug and it returns

```
Gmaps4RailsGoogle is not defined
Gmaps.map = new Gmaps4RailsGoogle();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should upgrade to the latest version of the gem: Gmaps4RailsGoogle didn't exist in 0.x.x.

Using 1.x.x, you'll need to require an additional file:

```
gmaps4rails.googlemaps.js
```

And 'gmaps4rails.js' is now 'gmaps4rails.base.js'

Using the installer, you'll have everything copied.

When using the gmaps helper, you need to provide a hash as first argument:

```
gmaps( :markers => { :data => @json } )
```

Some changes where necessary when coding 1.0.0, cause now multiple maps can be created on the same page. Anyway, all doc is in the wiki.
I guess all these indications answer your need.

Comment: Thanks, now markers works. This line `<%= gmaps({"markers" => { "data" => @json }}, true, false) %>` makes google maps works beautifully. :D